# Rails forms from scaffold don't work for columns added with a late migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, scaffolding, rails-migrations

I have a Rails project and I use the scaffold to generate my models and CRUD. Now I'm updating some models because I needed more columns or associations. 
But I notices that all the columns I've added later than the scaffold are never updated from my form. I added the field manually in the form but nothing is written in the database.

In my case, I have three entities:

**Document** and **People** which both belongs to **User**. 
When I generated the scaffold for People, I didn't have the association to User at first, and I added it with the following migration script:

```
class AddUserRefToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        add_reference :people, :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
end
```

And to be able to update through my form, I added the same thing I had in my Document's form which is working very well:

```
<div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :user, class: '...' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.map{|s| [s.firstname, s.id]}), class: '...' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems that the binding between the form and the model doesn't exist for this field (only for People entity because it works for Document).

And I have the same problem on Document on another column. The only pattern I found is the fact that I added those columns after doing the scaffold generation.

Do I miss something ? Do I need to do my update differently ? What is the best practice for adding new columns ?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have you permitted 'user_id'  in your controller(rails strong attributes)

Comment: Exact ! It works better with that ! Thank you very much!